# Java extract bit depth from jpeg-jfif picture

Tags: java, jpeg, bit-depth, metadata-extractor, jfif

I want to extract bit depth from jpeg file. I use [Metadata Extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) but it return all bit depth of all jpeg file as 8 bits but all picture have 24 bits color depth.

Sample result:

```
[JPEG] - Data Precision = 8 bits
[JPEG] - Image Height = 1632 pixels
[JPEG] - Image Width = 1275 pixels
[JPEG] - Number of Components = 3
```

Is there any other library and example for extracting bit depth?

Comment: The bit depth of 8 reported from Metadata Extractor may be per color channel. So it is still saying 24 bits total (8 for red + 8 for green + 8 for blue)

Comment: The exact format is JFIF and has 3 components. Does not this effect?

Comment: check out my imageinfo tool for the simplest way to interrogate a JPEG file for size/bit-depth info: https://github.com/bitbank2/imageinfo

Comment: @mohammad_1m2 can you open an issue on the project site and attach a sample image please?